# How to call id of an tag inside the query

Tags: jquery, html, onclick

I have generated some rows in jquery. I want to call myid from another jquery function. Is this possible. my code is below

```
<html>
<head><title></title>
<body>
<div id="body"></div>

</body>
</html>
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
$("#body").append("<table><tr><td id="myid">Value1</td><tr/></table>");


$("#body").find("#myid").click(function(){
alert("value is clicked");
});
});
</script>
```

But it is not working. pease anyone help to to solve my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to attach events to dynamically created elements. Try this:

```
$("#body").on('click','#myid',function(){
alert("value is clicked");
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/AEE77/)**

Comment: Thank you . SuPER WORKINGFINE

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $("#body").append("<table><tr><td id='myid'>Value1</td><tr/></table>");
});
$("#body").on('click','#myid',function(){
  alert("value is clicked");
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PPvG8/)

Answer (score 0):

I think your code looks ok, but you're probably getting an error because you're using double quotes (") within a table html string (which is a double quoted string), so basically:

```
"this is a "simple" string"
|----------|xxxxxx|-------|
```

In the above example, `simple` is not part of the string and is invalid JavaScript syntax. You have two options:

1. Alternate using " with ', e.g. `"this 'is' a valid string"` or `'this "is" a valid string'` are both valid strings
2. Escape the double quote character, e.g. `"this \"is\" a valid string"`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong assignment -

```
$("#body").append("<table><tr><td id="myid">Value1</td><tr/></table>");
```

You cannot use " inside another " without using escape character `(\)` 
So you write -

```
$("#body").append("<table><tr><td id='myid'>Value1</td><tr/></table>");
```

or

```
$("#body").append("<table><tr><td id=\"myid\">Value1</td><tr/></table>");
```